# Can't download image with python urllib

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib

I am trying to download an image with python and urllib.

This is my first attempt:

```
import urllib
url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg"
urllib.urlretrieve(url, "myimage.jpg")
```

The result is an empty (0 Byte) file called "myimage.jpg"

The image is accessible from browser, from the same link. So I tried change the  use user agent, using this script I found:

```
from urllib import FancyURLopener

url = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.jpg"

class MyOpener(FancyURLopener, object):
    version = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; it; rv:1.8.1.11) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11'

myopener = MyOpener()
myopener.retrieve(url, 'myimage.jpg')
```

The result is again an empty (0 Byte) file called "myimage.jpg".

Additional notes:

1. The **robots.txt** file is not accessible from browser: "access denied error" code 403.
2. In the url there is the word: 'ssl'

What can I do?

EDIT: The image is linked from another web domain. I noticed that the image is accessible from browser only if the first time I opened the image from this specific web domain. If I clear the cookies the image become unaccessible.

Comment: Why are you not sharing the urls?

Comment: @Psytho it was only a typing error. This is not the problem

Comment: @FlyingTeller sorry I can't share it

Comment: Does it work with random image files on the net? I tried out your first code sample and it worked fine.

Comment: Maybe the web server is checking the referrer in the headers and actively preventing hotlinking?

Comment: @sneep yes, it work with a random image from internet.

Comment: Voting to close this question, as it is unlikely that any answers can go beyond guessing what the issue might be

Comment: @FlyingTeller I asked a specific question, with all the details. Maybe someone has the answer, or can suggest an alternative to urllib that work.

Comment: @FabioDev as is clear from the comments, there is no issue with urllib (you can retrieve other images from the net). "With all the details" - You only left out the most important one (the url), for anyone else to reproduce this.

Answer (score 0):

It works *if* the URL exists:

```
import urllib

url = "https://www.lhorn.de/images/6cfYoU3.png"
png = urllib.urlretrieve(url, "nodejs-1995.png")
```

Comment: This not work with my url. The image is accessible from browser, but not from urlib.

Comment: Then you must check what your browser sends in the request that you do not send from Python.